# Multi Reflection XSS filter Bypass: Bypass this XSS filter and generate a popup

Tags: xss

$input = $_GET['user_name'];

echo(remove_xss($input));

remove_xss($input){

```
convert $input to lowercase
remove all "script"
remove all double and single quotes
remove all img, iframe, onclick, body, svg, button, div, video
remove all equal-to signs
```

}

Comment: Hi buddy. If you can, I'd recommend setting this up an online challenge. It's so easy for someone to build an exploit which you then say doesn't count. For example, does <sscriptcript>alert(1)</sscriptcript> solve it? Also, is this homework?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Could you provide some context? Are you trying to develop an XSS filter?

Comment: My question is about bypassing this xss filter code and to display a popup.

Comment: I have tried to bypass by adding Hex value in place of double and single quote but it didn't worked for me!

Comment: Yes this is a homework question. @paj28

Comment: Ok. I think `<sscriptcript>alert(1)</sscriptcript>` will do it. What do you think? The logic will remove `script` leaving `<script>alert(1)</script>`

Comment: Yes @paj28 it is right! Thankyou. 

Answer (score 0):

We can use the single pass removal of "script" against itself:

```
<sscriptcript>alert(1)</sscriptcript>
```

Comment: Yes! It worked!

Comment: @Cured_ - Great. I made it an answer so you can accept